# Enable syntax coloring in Geany?

Tags: python, colors, geany, syntax-highlighting

Online all the examples for Geany have syntax coloring, but I couldn't figure out how to enable this feature. I downloaded Geany, then created a new python file, but whenever as I type a keyword, number, string, ... the color stays black even after saving. Do I have to install an additional plug-in or is there an option somewhere to enable coloring?

Comment: To enable syntax highlighting ,save the file before coding......refer [here](http://geany.org/manual/dev/).....It will automatically highlight syntax

Comment: @Ravan, did not work if you highlight one variable and would like to see all variables with the same name highlighted.

Comment: I found on the geany plugins docu website a third party login which treats the `highlightword` problem. There is a difference between syntax `coloring` and `highlighting`, my fault.

Answer (score 4):

The "coloring" is called syntax highlighting and it is based on the detected file type. The file type detecting pretty much works on two paths:

1. from file extension. So a file with extension .py is recognized as Python file. This can be configured via Tools->Configuration Files->filetypes_extensions.conf
2. from manual choice from inside Document menu. So e.g. "Document->Set Filetype->Scripting Languages->Python source file" for setting Python

In some cases the so called shebang -- the #!/bin/... at the start of a file -- is also used to determine the file type.

In your case, you should ensure you have saved your file with a extension marked as Python and/or choose manually.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great collection of syntax highlight themes on Github. Please check:

https://github.com/codebrainz/geany-themes

Just follow the `Unix-like Installation` section:

> Extract the tarball and copy all of the files in the colorschemes directory to your ~/.config/geany/colorschemes/ directory. Create that directory if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Is this really related to syntax highlight or to color themes in general appearance (dark, light, etc.)?

Comment: @Timo Title on the github is misleading - it's related to syntax highlighting.

Comment: Thanks, I found on the geany plugins docu website a third party login which treats the `highlightword` problem.

Answer (score 0):

Besides connecting the file extension to a file type (like mentioned [in frian's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/666348/707507)), there is a general setting that was overseen by me. Make sure that in

- View --> Color Schemes...

there's not an entry selected that says "null" as the bracketed value. Im my case, this was: "github.conf (null)". You can either pick one of "Standard" or "Alternate" or even add further color schemes as described in [Michal's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/731265/707507).